# get listed category's id?

Tags: categories, list

ok - so i'm listing categories and their sub-categories. How can i get the ID of the category that's being shown with a function? ( i know what it is in the admin )

ie /category/events/women-in-art/

women-in-art-ID = ?

any help appreciated! Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about get_query_var('cat'). I think that should get the ID of the current category.

Comment: that's it! Thnks - got a bit stuck trying to use get_the_category().

Answer (score 1):

The "official" way to get the ID of the current category is `get_queried_object_id()` (also works with tags and custom taxonomies).

Comment: Cool. I used `get_queried_object()->term_id` until now.